# How to check whether all data in PostgreSQL child table have been copied successfully

Tags: postgresql, shell, scripting

As a beginner in PostgreSQL, I am writing a shell script to verify whether all data have been copied to the child table. I will then perform other activities. If all data have not been copied, the remaining code execution should be halted. In my script, all data from the `purchase_history_pre_partitioning` table are copied to the newly created `purchase_history` table using the `insert into` command.

To verify whether all data have been copied, I have written the following DO statement to compare the number of rows in the two tables. However, there is a syntax error. Please advise me on how to troubleshoot this.

DO statement:

> ```
> do $$
> begin
>   if (((select count(*) from purchase_history) !=
>          (select count(*) from purchase_history_pre_partitioning)))
>       then
>           EXIT        
> end
> $$
> ```

Error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "end" LINE 7: end
> ^
>
> SQL state: 42601 Character: 143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are meant to add a semicolon at the end of every SQL statement. Modify your script by adding a semicolon to `EXIT`, also end the if statement using `END IF`

```
DO $$
BEGIN
  IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM purchase_history) !=
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM purchase_history_pre_partitioning)) THEN
    EXIT;
  END IF;
END
$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It will make sure that all of the data from the purchase_history_pre_partitioning table is correctly moved to the PostgreSQL purchase_history table:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM purchase_history) != (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM purchase_history_pre_partitioning) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Data copy verification failed!';
  END IF;
END $$;
```

Hope it works :)